# PHP : Undefined index Error

Tags: php

Here is the section of code I only have a problem with at this time

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$term = $_POST['term']; <----- this would be line 22 in the error

$sql = mysql_query("select * from customers where F_Name like '%$term%' or L_Name like '%$term%'     or H_Phone like '%$term%'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) <= 0) {
// no results
echo 'No results found!';
} else 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
}   
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That comes from when term is not set as the post

Comment: stop using `mysql_query()`! try mysqli or PDO ! be modern !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST['term']` isnt being set when you initially go to that page.

What you need to do is check for the existence of that variable before you try and use it.

```
if (isset($_POST['term']))
{
    $term = $_POST['term'];
}
    else
{
    $term = 'something else';
}
```

or wrap all of that in the top part of that so you dont insert some random value into your database.

Also, you'll want to get friendly with at least [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). the `mysql` extension shouldnt be used.

Comment: You missed something . You have to declare `$term` first. add `$term = '';` in the first line.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor not necessary in PHP. The var is assigned in either the `if` block or the `else` block. It does not need to be declared otherwise.

Comment: it is a safe practice and can skip the else case. Why not ?

Comment: Yeah, in this case, you can skip the else case and the page will simply do nothing if that variable isnt set.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor you do not have to declare variables in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

When your page is loaded in a browser, it's typically done via the GET method; when this happens, your `$_POST` will be empty.

To only perform the search if a form is submitted you need code like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // do your search here
    $term = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'term', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
    if ($term !== null) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('select * 
            from customers 
            where F_Name like ? or L_Name like ? or H_Phone like ?");
        $stmt->execute(array("%$term%", "%$term%", "%$term%"));
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about `isset($_POST)` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Why would you want to do that?

Comment: *clarify:* can it replace `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') ` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor No, that's not the same; `isset($_POST)` is always true, but it could be an empty array.

Comment: id you really want to not use if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') - and I'm not sure why you wouldn't use this - then I would use !empty($_POST).

Comment: @exampleusername if you use `empty($_POST)` you can't tell a GET operation from a POST with missing fields.

Comment: @Jack exactly! You would only use that if you are explicitly using POST.

Answer (score 0):

using `$_POST[]` to set for a variable means your come from a previous form transaction that will tend `$_POST[]` to have a value else it will end up *un-exist* that can made an **error occur**

to generally give an example.

if a form like this is submitted

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<input name='term' value='SampleValue'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

you will end up getting a `$_POST['term']` variable with a value of the `<input name='term'>`

else if not

`$_POST['term']` will be un-exist and will generate a `ERROR`